# How to listen to new Sms in Android

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to listen to new sms(Message) with the help of **BroadcastReceiver**, but it is keep on listening to messages throughout the application and even after closing the app, so what to do??

Whether there is any other way to listen to sms or latest method as IntentReceiver kind of solutions(available over I-net) are deprecated and not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Ankit, just check this out, is this what u needed, .............

https://github.com/vivdub/DynamicSMSReceiver

Thanks

Comment: Hey brother... thank you very much, i had prepared this code same way but class called receiver in this source made lot of difference and had registered receiver in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 5):

If you register an Activity or Service as a BroadcastReceiver in the AndroidManifest.xml file, then the broadcast notifying it of the message will be received even if your Activity isn't open. If you only want your app to receive a notification that an SMS has arrived ONLY when it is open, you need to register a BroadcastReciever for SMS messages in the onResume method, using one of the [registerReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter))  methods and then un-register it in your Activity's onPause() method using [unregisterReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)). That way your app will stop listening for SMS messages when it isn't open.

Comment: Hey sam, thanks for replying.. but i have created a class and extended with BroadcastReceiver and in AndroidManifest file by <receiver> so whether i need to change it to service or activity or this may work or this may not properly work in future, please tel me what should i do, shall i show you my code

Comment: Vladimir, it seems you have discovered why my hyperlink wasn't working (I did try to fix it, but this problem always happens) How did you fix it?

Comment: I found solution,how to register and unregister receiver as you had explained, available in last answer. Thanks for ur response.

Answer (score 3):

You need to dynamically register and [unregister](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29) your `BroadcastReceiver`. 
So, when you detect that your application gets closed, just unregister your receiver.
See more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: Hey thanks, and you trying to say i have to use BroadcastReceiver only or there is any other way

Comment: BroadcastReceiver was especially designed for things such alarm or sms receiving. You'd better use it.

Comment: okay, thanks. so now i need to register and unregister broadcastReceiver dynamically right. Let me see.