# Listening for a particular keyword from a particular number in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sms

I need to know of some way to make my application listen to a particular keyword (an ip address) from a particular number.

Comment: Are you asking to find a keyword in a number such as finding 213 inside a larger number such as 4321390? Pattern matching?

Comment: Oh no no.. I will receive an sms containing only one keyword (an ip address say 12.12.12.12) Thats all. Preferably from a specific phone number.

Comment: Here's an example of a BroadcastReceiver that listens for SMS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver. Make sure that you add the correct permissions to your manifest, or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

[I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address) this great IP matching regex

ValidIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";

[Edit] [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470318/how-to-listen-to-new-sms-in-android) is a good link on how to work with incoming SMSs.

[Edit] [And another one.](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/)

Comment: THanks! But what I'm looking for is the android code snippet for listening and reacting to the sms.. I'm not really specific about the validity of the ip keyword the sms will contain. :)

Comment: Ah, you forgot to mention the SMS part.  See my edit for what I found with a Google search.

Comment: Hi. I tried out the methodology given here.. https://github.com/vivdub/DynamicSMSReceiver/blob/master/SMSReceiver/src/com/receiver/SMSReceiver.java   Its exactly what I wanted buuut there is one big issue. The thing is it bundles data and throws it. Unfortunately, my application is entirely built into the mainActivity itself. I want control to stay in the mainActivity. Is there any possible way to get the whole thing working in a single activity?